# Directadmin: Existing user with enabled SSH access can't login

Tags: centos, ssh

I've been using directadmin for a while now. But I can't figure this one out.

Today a customer wanted to have SSH access so I enabled SSH access on the user he uses to login to his FTP.

I tried logging into the user with SSH and it did not work.
When trying to login it returns `Access denied`

So I checked the `/var/log/secure` and it shows `Failed password for invalid user example from 1.2.3.4 port 56789 ssh2` Because it returns this error I thought that maybe the password was not set for the user since the user already existed and I enabled SSH access by modifying the user's rights. What I tried next was a simple `passwd example` and just reset it's password and try logging in. Unfortunately it did not work.

After that I read on some forums that when adjusting right's of old accounts, it was possible for Directadmin not to create the `AllowUsers` in the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file. But it was there like so `AllowUsers example`

Restarting sshd did not work.

What else could I check to see why I can't login?

OS: Centos 7

Panel: directadmin 1.53

**UPDATE**

After changing the `LogLevel` in the sshd_config to `DEBUG` from `INFO` I can see in `/var/log/secure` it returns `User example from 1.2.3.4 not allowed because not listed in AllowUsers`

Comment: How does your `sshd_config` look like? Especially the `AllowUsers`/`DenyGroups` options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that the SSH server got stuck and could not restart. So when DirectAdmin modified the rights of the user it could not restart SSH Server.

I tried to manually restart it but it always failed. When I tried `systemctl status sshd` it showed that the SSH server as `inactive`. Yet I am logged in? I manually killed the ssh server process and started it from the directadmin panel. After that I could login with the modified user.